# What can i do to up electrical amps in my house via fuse breaker

Tags: electrical-panel

i have in my home 120/240 Volt Main Service - Service Size: 100 Amps  I have a renter in the basement so he has cooking appliances and tv and refrigerator plugged in so we keep blowing fuses . What should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: To be clear, do you have fuses or circuit breakers?

Answer (score 6):

### Call an electrician!

Given how little information you've posted, and given the additional complexities / loads introduced with an income suite (additional fridge, microwave, stove, etc), this is best handled by a professional.

#### Do not, under any circumstance, replace a fuse with a bigger fuse (i.e., one with a larger current rating).

Doing that is an extreme hazard and fire risk.

A fuse or circuit breaker is sized to be the smaller of the following: the current rating of the smallest wire in the circuit and the rating of the receptacles or fixtures in the circuit. In order to increase the size of the fuse, you need to re-run all of the wire in the circuit with bigger wire, or run all new (bigger) wire to all of the receptacles / fixtures and properly disable the old wiring.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't much a homeowner can do here. It'll require an upgrade to the panel, most likely. It's probably time to get a modern breaker panel installed anyway.

Comment: Agreed, and be prepared for some not insignificant cost. Your question implies that there are circuits that are shared between the main and rental units, which indicates that the electrical work was not properly designed for a separate rental unit. Aside from the panel, fixing this may require running new wires (which likely means punching holes in drywall). As is usual with this type of thing, it takes 10x the effort to fix something done incorrectly over just doing it right the first time.

Comment: I disagree, there's a lot they can do.  They can learn how their house is wired, and learn how to avoid causing trips, paint their receptacles colors and cooperate so they split loads across pink and orange instead of putting everything on purple. They can identify underused circuits and pay an electrician to move a few receptacles from one circuit to another.  They can learn electrical for the day they quit renting, and can fix their own home themselves their way.

Answer (score 4):

### It's how you use power

100A is plenty of service.  The problem is that you and the tenant are using power in an uncoordinated or unthinking way.

A house's electrical system is subdivided into *circuits*.  By law, any circuit which serves receptacles (you know, sockets) is 15 amps or 20 amps, depending on the wire being used (14 AWG or the larger 12 AWG).  Since volts are 120, and watts are volts x amps, circuit capacity is 1800 or 2400 watts.

A typical plug-in kitchen appliance which makes heat is 1500 watts.  Two of them will overload any circuit, not immediately but after a minute or three. (that's why you can often get away with making toast or microwaving something quick).  The newest kitchens have 2 circuits for receptacles, for that reason, and even that is not enough for a cook.

If you know what you are doing, you can make sure you don't put too much load *on any one circuit*.  But you can't do that blind; you must know which sockets are on which circuit.

### Step 1: Map your house

First, and in coordination with the tenant, turn off one circuit at a time, and go around checking every receptacle and appliance, and see what has gone out.  The goal is to map them all.  You could get a label-maker and label them "circuit 1", "circuit 2" etc.  Or you could get artsy and pop the receptacle covers off and paint them colors.

The point is, you want to know exactly *which* devices, lights, and receptacles are on *which* circuit breaker or fuse.  And also, what people are plugging into which receptacle.

Next, figure out how many watts each device is taking.  If it states amps, multiply by 120 to get watts.  If it states VA, that's "close enough" to watts. Most appliances will have a nameplate which states this information.  If it doesn't, you can measure it with a $30 power monitor like a "Kill-a-Watt".

### Step 2: Plan your usage

Now you can strategize: who's putting what load on which circuits?  Most likely, you'll find that you both happen to be putting a *lot* of load on one or two circuits, while others are barely loaded at all.

Now you know what's going on, you can work around that, by rearrangement or agreement.

Or, you can do a bit of electrical work and move a few receptacles from one circuit to another, to even things out.

### How to save money at it

I gather you don't want to spend a metric ton of money on this.  OK.

In most jurisdictions, you can fix your own house you live in, but must hire an electrician to work on a rental unit.  So do the absolute minimum work for now, until the tenant leaves and you can reclaim the unit for family.  Meanwhile, get ready.  The next step is to roll up sleeves and learn how to do electrical work.

Look at books at the library or big-box home-improvement stores *(the one thing they are good for - books).*  Find a book that really speaks to you, and learn it well.  Learn to do excellent, picky, detailed work. Spend some time reading on here too.  A city inspector doesn't expect good work from homeowners, so you have to dazzle him with fastidious attention to detail that's technically perfect.  It's not that hard, just a bit of learning, that too many people try to shortcut or skip.

### A master plan

Now that you know what to do, make a "master plan" for wiring the house.  This is typically a compromise between what you want, and what is possible without ripping up a bunch of drywall or doing complicated wire fishing.

You know how most kitchens only have 2 circuits?  You can put in more if you want - about $10 in wire and $25 for a GFCI breaker per additional circuit; hardly a crushing expense if you DIY.  Heck you could even split the double receptacles and put each socket on a separate circuit!  For that reason, I like *really large* service panels, 42-space, 60-space or more.  I know when you have 8 fuses, 24 spaces seems like a lot.  But bigger panels cost about $3/space, and it's cost-prohibitive to change later.

You may want to think about 2 panels - one for each occupancy.  If you make each of those a sub-panel off a new main panel, this would also allow you to "sub-meter" so you can charge each occupant for their usage. Since your service is 100A, I would install a small 100A *main* panel serving a large sub-panel for each occupancy. This is very DIY-friendly since you never need to mess with the main panel, and can entirely shut off either sub-panel with the other still live.  It's also ready for the power company to serve each panel separately with its own meter and billing.

Tenants's gone? Now pull the permits for the big plan, and get to work.

If you do my "main panel/subpanels" plan, you should be able to keep most of your house energized most of the time while working, by energizing the sub-panel you're not working on, and even using the old fuse box as a sub-sub-panel.

Complete the work. Clear all your inspections.  Then up-and-decide you'd like to rent the unit after all!

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem -- you effectively are trying to create 2 dwelling units where there was only 1 before.  This brings *all sorts* of Code requirements into play (not just electrical ones!), and exposes *you*, as the landlord, to liability in case the tenant wants to play hardball about it, or if something bad happens for that matter.

I'd talk with a good GC about this -- you may need to do other renovations (such as plumbing and structural/layout for egress reasons) in addition to the boatload of electrical work you just signed up for.